# ImportError: cannot import name connections

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I wanted to include full text search in my django application. I am using whoosh-haystack for this.When I include whoosh and haystack in my installed apps,and execute the command `./manage.py`, I am getting an import error. Can anyone sort this out.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whoosh',
    'haystack',
    'galleryApp',
    'galleryAdmin',
]
```

The error which I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/admin.py", line 13, in <module>
    from haystack import connections
ImportError: cannot import name connections
```

Comment: What version of haystack are you using?
Do you have `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS` configured in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes,I have HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS configured in settings.py

Comment: Can you please tell me the command to know the haystack version in terminal.

Comment: What's in HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS?
You can see the version running: `pip freeze | grep haystack`

Comment: django-haystack==2.4.0
haystack==0.31

Comment: `HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
 'default': {
 'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
 'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/blog'
 },
}`

Comment: Try `pip uninstall haystack`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106913/discussion-between-sander-van-leeuwen-and-swathi-pantala).

Comment: @SwathiPantala It seems my answer below has helped more people to solve the problem. Could you please accept that as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `haystack` is conflicting `django-haystack`.
(Re)moving it will fix the issue.

See [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106913/discussion-between-sander-van-leeuwen-and-swathi-pantala) for details.

Comment: I am unable to uninstall haystack. I is giving me an error. Please suggest a method to remove it.

Comment: Which version of haystack should I install?

Answer (score 6):

The above did not work for me.

What worked for me was this:

- `pip uninstall haystack`
- `pip uninstall django-haystack`
- `pip install django-haystack`

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `__init__.py` file inside python `sitepackages/haystack` folder. This may be due to the absense of `__init__.py`. The `__init__.py` has the connection attribute. If that is not available try to uninstall and install/manually write the `__init__.py` file from github source.